# DatastoreFailureException: internal error

Tags: google-app-engine

Just started getting this error - having made no code change.
GAE/J on Datastore Datanucleus JDO/JPA version: v1
my app on EU servers don't run.
US unaffected currently.

Suspect Google have broken something internally.

can anyone concur?

Comment: Same issue here, with EU servers...

Comment: recovering gradually - latencies still high.

Comment: This happened twice today for me, around 9:45 and 17:50 CET. Thanks for posting this, so I know I am not the only one. As usual, the Google AppEngine status page does not mention anything.

Comment: yes, same for me yesterday on EU

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I started seeing a similar problem starting around 40 minutes ago. EU-based servers for my app as well.  Refreshing works about 50% of the time.

Comment: ok, interesting thanks.  Nothing from Google yet but have raised an issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13551

Comment: none of my hundreds of users can use my app right now in EU, makes no difference if I go back a few versions.

Comment: What helps for me is to kill the instance(s) of my application. Google will start new instances, which can use the datastore. However, latencies are still high.