# Google Appengine Java Frequent Restarts Lately

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Yes, I have seen, such questions have been asked before, but they are old, and there should be new reason now?

I have a tiny, low traffic Java Application hosted on GAE. Updates are infrequent, performance is not critical and so the Application seemed to run fine for days and weeks **till about 2-3 weeks ago**.

Since then more and more restarts of the application happened (I have a notification on that) and it has gotten worse now every day. Right now it seems like every single http request to the GAE instance triggers an application restart. Right now it is down to 90 seconds between restarts.

Looking into stackdriver traces, it shows, that worst request durations have increased from around a second per request up to 5 seconds only during last week. It was even faster 2 weeks ago. And the major time consuming part of these traces a task I do not know called /cloud_debugger.DebugletStarted .

Can anybody tell me, what is going on here?
Is there any way to obtain more information, what is going on?

Comment: Possible consequence of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221774/datastorefailureexception-internal-error (did some more digging and found the corresponding error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add a conclusion. It was then, when Google itself had a problem with its hosting and so the restarts actually came from the hosting site. Unfortunately it is so long ago, that I do not find the document by Google confirming this.