# Suddenly start / stopping instances

Tags: google-app-engine

Today we suddenly had a problem with standard environment app-engine instances being restarted all the time (eg every 10s or so) with basic scaling. Switching to manual scaling "solved" the problem, so it most probably has nothing to do with crashes etc. Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: Seems you're not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226023/google-appengine-java-frequent-restarts-lately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was actually an infrastructure problem at Google:

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-datastore/17002